# Retrieving contact and company GUID from ACT!

Tags: c#, guid, act

I'm currently working on a program in C# that works with data from ACT!. To be able to search and update a record you need to use the GUID.  The only way I have been able to get a GUID from the framework is when I create a new record.

How can I retrieve GUIDs from existing records in ACT!?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends which version of ACT! you have, but you'll almost certainly need the ACT! SDK.

That can be downloaded from here:  [ACT! SDK Download](http://www.act.com/partners/addonpartners/sdk/index.cfm)

There's a good post on the [ACT! developer forum](http://community.act.com/sage/?category.id=ActDevNet) that has a .zip file attachment.  The attachment contains some developer training materials, posted by a Sage employee, and within that material is a complete example for manipulating contact data.

From the included "readme":

> Insights2007ACTSDKTraining.zip
>   contains three files:
>
> ACT! SDK Training.pdf is the
>   presentation that was used for the
>   session.
>
> Samples.zip contains a contact-bound
>   control demonstrating entity data
>   binding and design-time capabilities.
>
> Act.DevNet.Extensibility.Plugin.zip is
>   the pluin template.  Copy it to your
>   Visual Studio
>   2005\Templates\ProjectTemplates
>   directory.  It will then be accessible
>   via File->New Project, Select Visual
>   C#, under My Templates.

The link for this is: [ACT! SDK Training Session Material](http://community.act.com/sage/board/message?board.id=ADN_Downloads&thread.id=10)